# Send different email response based on form options?

Tags: webforms, emails, navigation

I need to set up a *Request Download* form in which users choose which software they want from a drop-down. Is there any way to make it, so they are sent a unique email for each software? If not, is there a way to just show different responses on form submit?

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same problem a while ago. I wrote a blog post on it (link below) if you need more information. Basically you can change the email that gets sent based on the input of the form by creating your own webform-mail-[node-id].tpl.php. Within this template you can change the content based on submission data in the $submission variable.

```
<?php   
  if ($submission->data[1]['value'][0] == 'General Application'){
    print 'Thank you for submitting your resumé and covering letter'."\n\n";   
  } else {
    print 'Thank you for submitting your resumé and covering letter for the position of '.$submission->data[1]['value'][0]'."\n\n";   
  } 
 ?>
```

http://bouncingorange.com/blog/201204/custom-email-templates-webform

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: Try: https://web.archive.org/web/20160511081132/http://bouncingorange.com/blog/201204/custom-email-templates-webform :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) and [webform rules integration](http://drupal.org/project/webform_rules).

- **RULES**

  > The Rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally executed actions based on occurring events (known as reactive or ECA rules). It's a replacement with more features for the trigger module in core and the successor of the Drupal 5 [workflow-ng](https://www.drupal.org/project/workflow_ng) module.
- WEBFORM RULES

  > This module adds rules integration on webforms.
  >
  > Did you ever want to react on webform submission using rules but couldn't find the proper event?
  >
  > Webform Rules makes it possible to catch webform submissions by rules and do whatever you'd like to do with it (meaning: do whatever rules let you do with it).