# Send a mail automatically with content/attachment using webform using rules

Tags: rules, webforms, emails

In Drupal 7 a want people to fill in a webform with their email/tel/etc..and finally can choose some options.
When the submit the form, I want them to get automaticcaly more information about the chosen options, by sending automaticly a pdf by mail or permission to some content. Rather not with subscribing, also anonymous users.
Is this possible with rules and webform (I also installed webform rules).
When you need more information just let me know.

Thanks very much in advance!!!

Pieter-Jan Derks
Holland

Comment: I have tried to edit the question to make it clear. But, there are some parts of question I don't understand. What do you mean by "pdf by mail or permission to some content" how do you intend to send _permission_ to a user? Also didn't understand what do you mean by _Rather not with subscribing, also anonymous users_

Comment: I am sorry that I am not claer enough. Maybe I think the wrong way. I trie to be more clear. A user submits a webform with the option in the form 'tomatos' He wants more specifications about tomatos. When he submits the form, I would like him to send automaticly more information about tomatos. In what way, it doens't matter that much. Rather a mail with an attachment. But it can also be a predefined mail with information about a tomato. They must have the opportunity for more options (e.g. mushrooms or peas) Did I clear my question this way?

Answer (score 1):

Pieter - I think this [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36868/send-different-email-response-based-on-form-options) can be helpful. You would use MIME mail to add attachments and send rich emails.

Comment: Yes maybe it is. I read about it. I think I have to do some adaptions to my server (pear)? Do you thinks there is a good tutorial about mimes/rules